# How do I know the second line position in JS?

Tags: javascript

```js
var flight = `
  KE 925 H 18SEP 6 ICNAMS DK1  1405 1855  18SEP  
  KL1733 H 18SEP 6 AMSBRU DK1  2130 2215  18SEP
`;    
    
console.log(flight.substr(49, 7))
```

I have this string `flight` and I want to target the 1st position of the second line.

This is the only way i know :

```
flight.substr(49, 7)
```

49 means the character in the 49th position. However, the number of characters in the first line changes frequently so its not possible to write `flight.substr(49, 7)` statically.

So how do I know the 0th position of the second line?

im looking for something like `flight.substr(secondline 0, 7)`

Comment: just a suggestion : i dont think these `<pre id="demo11"></pre>` tags and the extra `document.getElementById(demo11).etc` are needed for the question

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the second line, I would use the a regular expression and split

```
const re = new RegExp('\r\n|\r|\n');
flight.split(re)[2]
```

you're getting index 2 because we're splitting at the line breaks and you start with a line break giving us an empty string in index 0.

Comment: So 3rd or 4th line… how to get?

Comment: Just change the index number. The splits are returned as an array

Comment: Oh I understand.
By the way, why did you use 'new'? (new RegExt('.... )

Comment: That's how you create a regular expression. The regular expression I used is looking for any variation of 'new line'. Here's some information on them:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1):

Programming is not about repeating code and HTML.
If I might suggest a different approach using RegExp to parse your lines into full-blown tickets

```js
const flight = `KE 925 H 18SEP 6 ICNAMS DK1  1405 1855  18SEP  
KL1733 H 18SEP 6 AMSBRU DK1  2130 2215  18SEP`;

const EL_flights = document.querySelector("#flights");

const parseFliResCode = (ticket) => {

  const [code, flight, dd, num, from, to, seat, dt, at, ad] =
    /^(.{8}) (.{5}) (.) (.{3})(.{3}) (.{4}) (\d{4}) (\d{4}) +(.{5}) *$/
    .exec(ticket);
    
  return {
    flight, num, seat, 
    from, [`departure date`]: dd,  [`departure time`]: dt,
    to, [`arrival date`]: ad,  [`arrival time`]: at,
  };
  
};

flight.split("\n").forEach((code) => {
  const obj = parseFliResCode(code);
  const HTML = Object.entries(obj).reduce((h, [key, val]) =>
    h + `<div class="cell">
      <span class="key">${key}:</span>
      <span class="val">${val}</span>
    </div>`
  , "");
  EL_flights.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<div class="ticket">${HTML}</div>`);
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box}
body {font: 14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

.ticket {
  border: 1px solid hsl(150 40% 80%);
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background: hsl(150 40% 94%);
}

.ticket .cell {
  padding: 3px 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 33.333%;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.ticket .key {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.ticket .val {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="flights"></div>
```

RegExp example on [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xi2d7y/3)

Comment: Awesome reply for me. I imagined programming like this.
However, I am a beginner programmer.
Is there a way to assign each value a 'variable'?

Comment: @user16468332 each value is already a variable! After the `const obj = parseFliResCode(code);` add `console.log(obj);` and see for yourself in console. You'll see that all those variable name properties like `"flight", "departure date"` etc. are defined inside the `parseFliResCode` function!

Comment: @user16468332 `const [code, flight, dd, num, from, to, seat, dt, at, ad] =
  /^(.{8})\s(.{5})\s(.)\s(.{3})(.{3})\s(.{4})\s(\d{4})\s(\d{4})\s+(.{5})\s*$/
    .exec(ticket);` see the const variables? :)

Comment: Yes, I can see 'variables'. But Now I am studying your code for my code. Thank you so much Roko :)